# Call MVC method from webpage in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC app and on one page I have the following Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetAuthCode/",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function () {
        }
    });
```

This calls an ActionResult method in my ASP app:

```
public ActionResult GetAuthCode()
    {
        //Do Stuff
        Return View();
    }
```

I would like it to navigate to the view once the method has 'Done Stuff' however it doesnt return to the view but returns to the ajax call once completed.

How can I call the method from the webpage and allow it to redirect to the specified view as the ajax call does not seem to do it.

Comment: does your view with name `GetAuthCode` exists and try setting `contentType:html`. Additionally you can set `window.location.href = '/Home/GetAuthCode/'` in your ajax success.

Comment: This is not correct.  That means that GetAuthCode will be called twice and it could easily contain functionality you do not want to occur twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do the redirection in javascript, then use:

```
window.location.href = '/Home/GetAuthCode/';
```

Comment: Excellent thats exactly what I needed, I have to wait 5 mins then i can accept your answer :)

Comment: Do not do this in the scope of the AJAX success call please.

Comment: @ChristianDuvall with this code I wont need the ajax call at all anymore

Comment: Precisely, so why use JavaScript at all? Why not just route with a link?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to navigate to a new page, then don't use the AJAX call at all, just create a route and go to it.

```
<a href="/Home/GetAuthCode">I just did something and went to the returned view.</a>
```

Comment: And how would I call that using javascript? Could you put your example into a javascript function?

Comment: Why do you want do use javascript?  It's a simple navigation.  The point of calling something with AJAX is that you do not want to route away, you want to take action then make some dynamic change within the  site itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect in success function of ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetAuthCode/",
        type: "Post",


        success: function (data) {
window.location.href= data.Url;

        }
    })
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult GetAuthCode()
    {
        //Do Stuff
        return Json(new { Url = "urlsing"});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetAuthCode", "Home")',
         data: { },
         type: "GET",
         contentType: 'application/json',
         success: function () 
         {
            if(result.yourValidationIsOk)
            {
                document.location.href = '@Url.Action("RedirectAction", "Home")';
            }
            else
            {
                alert("error occured");
            }
         }
      });
```